# OpenTK - How to debug an instant crash?

Tags: c#, debugging, opengl, crash, opentk

I'm using OpenTK in my C# application to draw on the screen with OpenGL. I've had it working but now I've introduced a bug by refactoring the code in a way that still serves the exact same information the the RenderFrame function.

The whole program crashes after calling the GameWindow constructor. Nothing prints on the console. Visual Studio debugger just shuts down. It seems like I have no means to know what causes the crash.

How to debug an external library?

Comment: What makes you think that there even is a crash? What about the program just exiting?